# I want to create a mesh from a silhouette

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices, generated

I'm working in Unity and thus coding in C#, but any idea or a place to start is welcome.

I don't really know how to describe my problem, and if there is a 'simple' solution for it, but I'll try.
I have an object (probably going to limit myself to simple shapes) that casts 2 shadows. 
I'd like to generate a mesh that is the shape of that shadow. 
As you can see on the image below, I drew the desired meshes in green.

[desired meshes drawn in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0KUs.png)

I've messed around with altering the vertices of my initial mesh, and in some specific cases (objects with no rotation) found a solution, but I haven't found one that's works well enough.
Does anyone have an idea that could work?

Thanks in advance, 
Bart

Comment: You could try using Raycasts from the light sources through the corners of your red cube and check where the ray hits the wall

Comment: how do you know how "thick" the object should be? a shadow is 2D

Comment: It is gonna be fixed width. 1 Unit for example.

Comment: you do not have to "generate a mesh".  simply, take a box, and change the length/width (that is to say, by changing the **scale**) and you're done.  it's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the time to create a project that does exactly what you said:
[Preview it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsfIA.gif)

## The Method

Using **raycasts** I calculated the projected vertices of a specific object from a light source. The method may seem inefficient but as long as the specified mesh has a low vert count everything should be fine.

Then by taking the average of projected vertices I calculated the position of the projected cube. 
`Vector3 averagePosition = new Vector3(verticies.Average(vector => vector.x),
                                              verticies.Average(vector => vector.y),
                                              verticies.Average(vector => vector.z));`

And by taking the range each of the projected vertex position components (x,y,z) I calculated the scale of the cube.`Vector3 averageScale = new Vector3(verticies.Max(vector => vector.x) - verticies.Min(vector => vector.x), verticies.Max(vector => vector.y) - verticies.Min(vector => vector.y), normalScale);`

Note: I am not generating a whole new mesh. I am just manipulating the transform of a pre-made cube with a script attached.

Downside is that this method is only limited to one axis so far. Can be fixed.

## Download the project from Github

GitHub link: https://github.com/MyIsaak/Shadow-Mesh/tree/master

Would be great if you could commit any improvements you make to help the community. You are free to use this project for commercial and non commercial use.

Comment: I really appreciate the time and effort you spend trying to help, thanks.

After a lot of trail and error I came to a similar result, but not nearly as clean and straightforward as your code, so this is really helpful.

Now, the main problem with morphing a mesh that has the shape of a shadow is that a shadow doesn't always have the same shape or as much vertices as the original object. (example in link)

But I'm confident that I can solve that using your code, as I'm able to find the needed vertices to build the desired mesh from.
![Example and outline](http://imgur.com/a/5xAYI)